# C#4 dynamic and unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, .net-core-2.1

Using netcore2.1,

I have a service (in assembly 'Domain')

```
public class MuSuperService
{
    private IValueStorage _storage 
    //of cource _storage DIed in ctor

    public void MySuperAction(dynamic value)
    {
        _storage.Store(value.SuperValue);
    }
}
```

And I trying write unit test to this method (in assembly 'Domain.Test')

```
 [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Domain")]
 public class MuSuperServiceTest
 {
    //mock and setup all are hidden

    [Fact]
    public void CheckAction()
    {
        dynamic value = new ExpandoObject();
        value.SuperValue = 10;
        _service.MySuperAction(value);
    }
 }
```

But it faling with

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SuperValue' and no extension method 'SuperValue'

Where can be problem?

Comment: your error message doesn't match with dynamic objecct name

Comment: @Rahul where? 'object' is typename, 'SuperValue' is property name

Comment: your posted code has no variable named `object` then from where this error message came?

Comment: object isn't variable name. It is type name in exception. Error was on ` _storage.Store(value.SuperValue); `

Comment: then post code for `_storage.Store()` method

Comment: `_storage.Store()` doesn't call. if i try open `value.SuperValue` in watch list error still exist

Comment: @darkhac Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. There is currently not enough to do that in the question. There is too much room for assumptions that may skew the actual cause.